# Does research unix have any binary editor?

Tags: editors, history, binary

I cannot find any binary editor in v7 unix by reading volumn 1 of the manual.

Is there any?

Comment: Did you just jump through some kind of time warp portal?

Answer (score 1):

There's no hex editor built in, the closest you're going to have is combining `od` and the `ed` editor, both of which are available in Version 7. `vi` isn't included with Version 7, you could probably compile an old version since it was released about that time.

The man page of `od` should be useful. The man page of `ed`, not as much, but if you know sed, ed commands are a lot like sed since sed is based on ed. You can try reading tutorials [here](http://polarwave.openbsd101.com/ed.html) and [here](http://wolfram.schneider.org/bsd/7thEdManVol2/edtut/edtut.pdf) or just google "ed editor" "ed tutorial" and so on.

You could try building your preferred editor but I don't know how that will work out on an OS that is over 30 years old.